# Geometry of Lie Group Around Identity

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G$ be a continuous compact Lie group. And let $K,\ H$ be closed subgroups.

How can we take $W$ which is a small open set around $e$ and satisfies the following :

If $K\subset WH$ then $KH/H$ is a point in a coset space $G/H$.

Thank you in advance.